# can I use a variable's value as a new variable? How I can do that?

Tags: python

can I use a variable's value as a new variable? How I can do that?

a = "rajiv"

I want to set rajiv to another value
a = "1"

but I get a's value as 1 and not rajiv's

Comment: Also, I am not sure what is the value of 'a'

Comment: If you ever think you need to dynamically create variables, what you really need is a data structure of some sort. Probably a list or a dict.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `globals()`

```
>>> a = 'rajiv'
>>> globals()[a] = 1
>>> rajiv
1
```

Comment: my query is answered, thanks all

Comment: how I can write multiple variables and text to a file file.write(Issue',issue, "Reporter:",issue_reporter, "Created:",created,"Age of issue:",days_old") gives me syntax error

Answer (score 0):

You can use `globals()` like the others have suggested.
However, [it is thought to be bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158339/why-are-global-variables-evil)
I say utilize object in python

```
obj = {}
obj['a'] = 'foobar'
obj[obj['a']] = 'hello'
print(obj) # {'a': 'foobar', 'foobar': 'hello world'}
```